# If/Else in ModelBuilder not showing the correct True/False outcome

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, modelbuilder

I'm creating a model that queries the number of features in a feature class and runs one of two scripts depending on if the feature class is empty or not.

I'm using Get Count to calculate the number of features with the output being 'Feature Count'

I then have two calculate values 'Policy Detected' and 'No Policy Detected' both set to Boolean data types

Policy detected is:

```
FeatureCount(%Feature Count%)
def FeatureCount(n):
if n> 0:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

No Policy Detected is:

```
FeatureCount(%Feature Count%)
def FeatureCount(n):
if n >0:
    return False
else:
    return True
```

When there are features in the feature class (n>0), 'Policy detected' has a 'True' output and 'No Policy detected has a 'False' output - all correct!

When there are no features in the featureclass (n=0) then both 'Policy detected' and 'No Policy detected' show a False output instead of 'False and 'True'

Any ideas what's wrong?

.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You logic is flawed as well as the use of the Get Count tool.

Firstly if Get Count is returning a zero then in the world of model builder this is interpreted as FALSE. You have made this output the precondition to your Policy tools. So as your precondition is FALSE (because count is zero) then neither of the tools will run.

If you are attempting an if/then/else logic you need to be reading the [help file](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/analyze/modelbuilder/using-if-then-else-logic-for-branching.htm) and understanding how it is done in modelbuilder. There is lots of advice and examples to study.

Comment: So the precondition between the Get Count output and the Policy detected calculation is what's causing the problem? The 'Feature Count' output is an integer but the precondition assumes 0 = False?

Comment: I've tried the tool using 'n>1' as the condition and running it with Get count outputting   1 and >1 and the if/else works perfectly. As you said, the precondition assumes 0 is false and everything else is true. Thanks